# Relative directory Logic

Tags: directory

I've used emacs in various configurations over the years, but the one aspect I couldn't find a good proxy for is relative directory logic.

My goal is to use evil-mode + web-mode. I'm not interested in doing everything possible in emacs. I just want really good vim emulation and syntax highlighting. I think emacs does a better job of these things at the cost of added complexity and trying to parse emacs-lisp.

In Sublime Text you can "open a folder" and then when you go to open a file it assumes it's contained within the "current" directory.

In VIM I can "cd" to a directory and all all files I open are relative to that directory i.e. "e foo/bar.py" in the command prompt assumes `current_directory/foo/bar.py`.

**tl;dr Is there a simple way to "cd" to a folder, so that opening and searching for files to open are relative to that folder?** I've tried dired & projectile but wonder if there's a much simpler option that more closely maps to the UX of vim.

Answer (score 2):

There is command `cd`: `M-x cd` (or bind it to a key).

There is also Dired: `C-x d`, then `C-h m`.  Or `C-h r g dired`, which takes you to [node Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html) of the Emacs manual.

Both of those should help you.  See also variable `default-directory`, using `C-h v`.

`C-h f cd` tells you this:

> **`cd`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `files.el`.
>
> `(cd DIR)`
>
> Make `DIR` become the current buffer’s default directory.
>
> If your environment includes a `CDPATH` variable, try each one of
>   that list of directories (separated by occurrences of
>   `path-separator`) when resolving a relative directory name.
>   The path separator is colon in GNU and GNU-like systems.